# Передать по jqery в laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel5

подскажите пожалуйста 
Есть views и контроллер
Как передать переменную в контроллер ,выполнить запрос и вернуть его в views
К примеру по клике на кнопку значение переменной `$val` увеличивается на 1, а контроллер к примеру обрабатывает запросом  `Posts::where('user_id',$val)->get();` и возвращает результат.

Желательно не большой пример кода показать.Буду благодарен за любой ответ

Comment: Используйте ajax или fetch

Comment: Чем ваш вопрос отличается от предыдущего вашего вопроса, на который получен ответ и вам его снова опять предложили?